# telegram bot node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram, бот

если функция или метод, при котором если пользователь нажал старт и больше ничего не отправил , бот ему о себе напоминает через определенное время и если есть то как называется или можно документацию по ней . Зарание спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var users = [];
bot.on('new_chat_members', msg => {
   users.push(msg.chat.id);
   // здесь какой-то ответ
});
setInterval(() => {
   users.forEach(userId => {
      bot.sendMessage(userId, 'Давно не писали мне.');
   }
   users = []
}, 360000);
```

Как вариант.

Answer (score -1):

Это с `setTimeout`

```js
const oflineTime = 1000 * 10; 

const oflineMessage = "Вас уже довно нам не пишите";

var i;

function updateTimeout(id) {
    clearTimeout(i);
    i = setTimeout(()=>{
        bot.sendMessage(id, oflineMessage);
    }, oflineTime)
}

bot.on('new_chat_members', (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    updateTimeout(chatId);
});
```

Это с `setInterval`

```js
const oflineTime = 1000 * 10; 

const oflineMessage = "Вас уже довно нам не пишите";

var i;

function updateTimeout(id) {
    clearInterval(i)
    i = setInterval(()=>{
        bot.sendMessage(id, oflineMessage)
    }, oflineTime)
}

bot.on('new_chat_members', (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    updateTimeout(chatId)
});
```

Comment: За что минус? Обоснуйте